# C# Implementing SynchronizationContext OperationStarted and OperationCompleted in console app

Tags: c#, console, synchronization

New to programming in C# (came from Java) and trying to get familiar C#'s methodologies behind multi-threading.

I have the following class implemented as a SynchronizationContext in a console application:

```
public class AppSynchronizationContext : System.Threading.SynchronizationContext
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<FutureInvocation> future = new ConcurrentQueue<FutureInvocation>();

    private struct FutureInvocation
    {
        private readonly SendOrPostCallback sendOrPostCallback;
        private readonly object state;
        private readonly WaitHandle waitHandle;


        public FutureInvocation(SendOrPostCallback s, object st, WaitHandle waitHandle)
        {
            sendOrPostCallback = s;
            state = st;
            this.waitHandle = waitHandle;
        }

        public SendOrPostCallback SendOrPostCallback
        {
            get
            {
                return sendOrPostCallback;
            }
        }

        public object State
        {
            get
            {
                return state;
            }
        }

        public WaitHandle WaitHandle
        {
            get
            {
                return waitHandle;
            }
        }

    }

    /*
     *  Periodically polled on the main app thread.
     * */
    public void Poll()
    {
        DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
        int timeOut = 1500;

        while (!future.IsEmpty)
        {
            FutureInvocation f;
            if (future.TryDequeue(out f))
            {
                f.SendOrPostCallback?.Invoke(f.State);
                if (f.WaitHandle != null)
                {
                    AutoResetEvent e = (AutoResetEvent)f.WaitHandle;
                    e.Set();
                }
            }

            if((DateTime.Now - t).Milliseconds >= timeOut)
            {
                //If the elapsed time is >= timeout seconds, break and allow the main thread to continue (Other queued items will be done on next poll)
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Should block until SendOrPosTCallback completes, per my understanding
     * */
    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        WaitHandle w = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        FutureInvocation f = new FutureInvocation(d, state, w);
        future.Enqueue(f);

        //Block here.
        w.WaitOne();
    }


    /* Something goes here...*/
    public override void OperationCompleted()
    {
        base.OperationCompleted();
    }

    /* Something goes here...*/
    public override void OperationStarted()
    {
        base.OperationStarted();
    }


    /*
     * 
     * Add it to the queue without worrying about if the callback has completed..
     * */
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        FutureInvocation f = new FutureInvocation(d, state, null);
        future.Enqueue(f);
    }

    /*
     * Creates a deep copy of the existing Synchronization Context.
     * */
    public override SynchronizationContext CreateCopy()
    {
        AppSynchronizationContext s = new AppSynchronizationContext();
        foreach(FutureInvocation f in future)
        {
            s.future.Enqueue(f);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

I have a few questions regarding the implemtnation of a SynchronizationContext.

- Am I correct in thinking that Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state) blocks until the SendOrPostCallback delegate completes?
- I don't entirely understand what the role of OperationStarted and OperationCompleted is, what is their purpose and how can I implement them?

Comment: The documentation for each of those methods answers your questions about each of them.

Comment: Iv'e read the documentation on them that I could find.. `When overridden in a derived class, responds to the notification that an operation has completed.` To me this is to obscure, I still don't understand what it does.

Comment: It does whatever you override it to do

Comment: Well yeah, I gathered that much. Are you saying it has no intended purpose?

Comment: Here is an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/gg598924.aspx) from MSDN that should be helpful. It is linked from the documentation for `SynchronizationContext`. It might be helpful to describe what you are actually trying to accomplish in your program, because this seems like a bit of overkill if you just want to queue up some work items in your console app.

Comment: Of course it has an intended purpose.  The intended purpose is to allow overridden implementation to respond to a notification that an operation has completed.

Comment: @pstrjds Yeah, it is a bit overkill. It's partially for learning purposes but the console app is going to be using async/await throughout it and I wanted to have a SynchronizationContext so that continuations could be done on the main thread instead of ThreadPool threads so I can cut down on synchronization using locks/atomic operations. Thanks for the article, taking a look now.

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: @Steve in what way?

Comment: @Eladian Creating your own synchronization context.

Comment: @Steve except you are really knowing what you are doing ;o)

Comment: @Eladian You can have a look at https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext